# How does a ring generated by an element of it look like?

Tags: ring-theory

I know that in the group theory any group generated by an element $a$ of it takes the form $\{a^{n} | n \in \mathbb {Z} \}$.But I don't know how does a ring $R$ generated by one of it's element $a$ look like.Is it of the form $\{ra | r \in R \}$.If the answer is 'yes' then can we say that any ring containing the identity is generated by it's identity?

Please help me in understanding this concept.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But in my book it has been claimed that if a ring $R$ contains identity then $R$ is generated by it's identity.This is my problem.

Comment: it sounds like your book is trying to say that: "If $R$ has an identity element $1$, then $R$ is generated *as an $R$-module* by $1$." In my answer, I deal with the concept "generated as a ring" only, so I guess my answer is probably irrelevant to what you're trying to understand.

Comment: Are you sure your book doesn't say that the *ideal* generated by $1$ is always $R$? The *ring* generated by $1$ in $\mathbb Q$ is just $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me answer my own question.

I have just studied ideal.In my book it has been left as an exercise to show that "If $R$ is a ring then the ideal $\langle x \rangle$ generated by an element $x$ of $R$ is of the form $\{rx + xs + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{m} s_{i} x t_{i} + nx\ | r,s,s_{i},t_{i} \in R; m \in \mathbb {N}, n \in \mathbb {Z} \}$ and moreover if $R$ contains the identity then

$\langle x \rangle = \{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m} s_{i} x t_{i}\ | s_{i}, t_{i} \in R , 1 \leq i \leq m \}$."

I have proved this result. So, according to the above fact if $R$ is a ring with identity $1_{R}$ then

$\langle 1_{R} \rangle = \{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m} s_{i} t_{i}\ | s_{i}, t_{i} \in R , 1 \leq i \leq m \} = R$.

Which proves the claim.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what kind of “generation” you are meaning. I'll assume rings have an identity and subrings share it.

The *subring* of $R$ generated by $a\in R$ is the least subring of $R$ containing $a$. Thus it is the set of polynomial expressions in $r$ with integer coefficients, so an element of this subring has the form $m_01+m_1a+m_2a^2+\dots+m_ka^k$. More formally, it is the image of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]\to R$ such that $X\mapsto a$;

In particular, if $a=1$, we have that $R$ is generated as a ring by its identity if and only if it is a quotient ring of $\mathbb{Z}$. Note that the subring of $R$ generated by $a$ is always commutative.

If you mean the *submodule* of $R$ generated by $a\in R$, then you have to distinguish between left and right submodules. The left $R$-submodule of $R$ generated by $a$ is $Ra=\{ra:r\in R\}$; similarly, the right $R$-submodule of $R$ generated by $a$ is $aR=\{ar:r\in R\}$. They might differ if $R$ is not commutative. However, if $a=1$ they both coincide with $R$; thus the *submodule* (left or right) generated by the identity is the whole ring.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ there?  That would be interesting.

Comment: @TheGhostOfGaussPossessesMe Yes, I mean $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ where $X$ is an indeterminate.

Answer (score 3):

A ring generated by one element is the same thing as a quotient of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x].$ More generally, an $R$-algebra generated by one element is the same thing as a quotient of the polynomial ring $R[x].$ More generally still, an $R$-algebra generated by a set $X$ is the same thing as a quotient of the non-commutative polynomial ring $R[X].$

Quotients in this context turn out to be (essentially) the same thing as ideals, so what you're basically asking is: what are the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I don't know the answer to this question, but maybe someone can provide you with a link.

Comment: Sorry @goblin this goes beyond my head.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring). Note that wikipedia and I use slightly different notation; their capital $X$ is my little $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose that $R$ is an arbitrary ring with identity $1_R$. We can defined in general three kind of ideals: left, right and two-side ideals. If $r\in R$, then we have

$$\langle r]=\{ar:a\in R\}.$$
$$[r\rangle=\{ra:a\in R\}.$$
$$\langle r\rangle=\Bigl\{\sum_{i\in\Bbb{N}}a_irb_i:a_i, b_i\in R\Bigr\}.$$

In general these three ideals doesn't coincide, but it can be proved that if $R$ is conmutative, then they do coincide, and we can talk about the ideal (without adjetives) generated by $r$: $\langle r\rangle$.

Now, if your ring $R$ (not necessarily commutative) has an identity $1_R$, then the three kinds of ideals generated by $1_R$ are the same, i.e., $\langle 1_R]=[1_R\rangle=\langle 1_R\rangle$ because for $a\in R$ we have $a=a\cdot 1_R=1_R\cdot a$. So if $a\in R$, $a\in \langle 1_R\rangle$. This means that if we thought $R$ as an ideal, then $R=\langle 1_R\rangle$.

Comment: So @Xammm according to your concept any ring $R$ with identity can be thought of as an ideal containing $1$ and moreover if $R$ is commutative then $R$ can be thought of as an ideal generated by $1$.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. in general if an (left, right, two-sided) ideal $I$ of $R$ contains the identity or even an unit, then $I$ is the whole ring. This applies in particular if the ideal is $R$ itself. Also, it doesn't matter if $R$ is commutative or not, in any case $R$ can be thought as an ideal generated by $1$.

Comment: Interesting notation!